# how to use opc ua call method request with java opc library

Tags: java, opc-ua, opc

I'm trying to send the contents of a cvs file to an opc server via the call method request function.  In practice I should send an array with two strings, the first which would be the name of the machine file where I am going to write the parameters, and the second the name of the csv file where I have already written the parameters to send.  Can you give me some indications on which class to use of the Java opc foundation?  Thanks in advance

I tried calling the java library by invoking the call method but i can't figure out how to pass the parameters

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [SampleClient](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java-Legacy/blob/master/examples/basic/src/main/java/org/opcfoundation/ua/examples/SampleClient.java) in the OPC Foundation UA Java Legacy project, and see how it makes a Read call with a ReadRequest, you can now make a similar Call to make a method call with a CallRequest.

The [specification](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v105/docs/5.11.2) defines how to use the Call request in general.